# Left align using \tikz

Tags: align, tikz-styles

The current \tikz I'm using now is this below.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\signe}{m}{
    \tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node(O) [baseline,minimum width=25mm,inner sep = 0,align=center] {#1};}
}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \signe{(Help)} = Hello
  \item \signe{(Individual)} = Hello
  \item \signe{(Test)} = Hello
\end{itemize}
```

## Output

[image]

How to left align text & align = in same line as previous.

## Desired Output

**- Remember There shouldn't be `...`**

[image]

Comment: You can use `\tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node[baseline, text width=25mm, inner sep = 0pt, align=left] (O) {#1};}`, but why don't you just use `\makebox[25mm][l]{#1}`?

Comment: Thanks \makebox worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! To align text in a Ti*k*Z `\node`, you need to set the option `align=left` and give it a fixed width, for example using the option `text width`:

```
\tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node[baseline, text width=25mm, inner sep=0pt, align=left] (O) {#1};}
```

But if you only want to align text in a box of a certain width, it is probably much easier to just use `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\signe}{m}{
    %\tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node[baseline, text width=25mm, inner sep=0pt, align=left] (O) {#1};}
    \makebox[25mm][l]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \signe{(Help)} = Hello
  \item \signe{(Individual)} = Hello
  \item \signe{(Test)} = Hello
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]